# what is the 'Rails Way' to pass objects across multi (logical) tiers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm coming from the .NET world and I'm trying to figure out what the 'Rails Way' to pass an object across tiers in a multi-tier application.

I'm writing a multi carrier pricing API. Basically in my price controller I have access to the following parameters **params[:carrier]**, **params[:address_from]**, **params[:address_to]**, **params[:container_type]**, etc. I have a validation library, a compliance library and a price-finder library that each deal with a subset of the params.

In .NET the params would be encapuslated in data transfer objects (DTOs) or contracts. Before calling any of the libraries, they would be converted to domain objects (DOs) and each library would work on the DOs, thus avoiding a tight coupling on the DTOs. Ruby programming recommands the use of 'duck typing', so my libraries could work directly on params (even though you would access symbols and not objects/properties). Or should I marshall my params into a PriceRequest object and have my libraries work on the PriceRequest type?

Option 1:

```
class PricesController < ApplicationController
  def get
    CarrierValidator.validate(params)
    ...
  end
end

class CarrierValidator
  def self.validate(params)
    raise CarrierError if !Carrier.find_by_name(params[:carrier_name]).exists?
  end
end
```

Option 2:

```
class PricesController < ApplicationController
  def get
    pricesRequest = PricesRequest.new(carrier_name: params[:carrier_name], ...)
    pricesRequest.validate
    ...
  end
end

class PriceRequest
  attr_accessor : ...

  def initalize
    ...
  end

  def validate
    CarrierValidator.validate(self.carrier_name)
  end
end

class CarrierValidator
  def self.validate(carrier_name)
    raise CarrierError if !Carrier.find_by_name(carrier_name).exists?
  end
end
```

TIA,
J

Comment: can you post an example code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a type.  I would use **ActiveModel** to encapsulate the data (attributes) & business logic (validations & maybe some layer-specific methods for processing the data).

Basically, you want to be able to do Rails-y things in the controller like:

```
def get
  price_request = PriceRequest.new(params[:price_request])

  if price_request.valid?
     # do something like redirect or render
  else
     # do something else
  end
end
```

so you want to declare:

```
class PriceRequest
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :carrier, :address_from, :address_to, :container_type

  validates :carrier, presence: true
  validate :validate_address_from

  def validate_address_from
    # do something with errors.add
  end

  # and so on
```

This is a good place to start: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html

More details in the API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html

Hope that points you in the right direction...

Comment: I already chose to use the json_schema gem for the request json validation, which would take care of some of the validation rules in PriceRequest. But I guess that still wouldn't invalidate what you proposed since more complex validation business rules would still go into PriceRequest, right? Also, where would you put this file? /app/models, /app/business_models, /lib or /lib/domain_objects?

Comment: yeah, you could just use the model to wrap your json_schema call / config... app/models would work... it's entirely up to you - you can put any directory under app and it'll load